# Moving armature and bones using python code

Tags: python, animation, rigging, armature, bones

I am very new to blender and coding in python (less than 6 months). Can somebody please help me by suggesting how to select move, and manipulate armatures/bones?

I have downloaded a rigged person from blendswap and I am trying to program him into specific positions using python. This is for part of a project where the user inputs variables to define a crash scene in a CSV file. For instance they would specify in the file that the crash victim lands prone, in the fetal position etc. I have a CSV file import add-on I downloaded to handle this.

Ultimately then I would need to key frame the rig's position once it is programmed, so the person looks like they are getting hit by a car and falling into the defined position. Which I am also having trouble with...

Thank you for your help!